# How to make Android xml Linerlayout at the bottom of the activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

How do I make LinearLayout in Android Studio at the bottom of the page. The result from the code below

I want the highlighted darken layout to be at the bottom of the page.
[image: I want the highlighted darken layout to be at the bottom of the page.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainPage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/taptoscan"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barcode"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tap to Scan"
        android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <!--here is the layout i want to put at the bottom of the page-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above code I tried the below and did not worked.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: Use the outeralyout as relativelayout

Comment: @Ticherhaz i tried that too its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RelativeLayout at the outside. Something like this, and then ADD new one LinearLayout after that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/taptoscan"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/barcode" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
            android:text="Tap to Scan"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--here is the layout i want to put at the bottom of the page-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Frame Layout as base layout to do it in the best way, it's gonna work definitely
Just use layout_gravity="bottom" in the LinearLayout which you want at bottom and 
Just like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/taptoscan"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/barcode" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
            android:text="Tap to Scan"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach below would help you achieve your design specifications with zero overlappings. Basically, there are four key steps:

1. Change your root layout to a *RelativeLayout*.
2. Inside the *RelativeLayout*, add a *LinearLayout* that would contain your *Button* and your *TextView*.
3. Inside the same *RelativeLayout*, add the *LinearLayout* that you intend to pin to the bottom of the screen.
4. Make sure yoU set the first LinearLayout on top of the second by using the `android:layout_above=""` attribute.

Now, here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainPage">


  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView">


      <Button
          android:id="@+id/taptoscan"
          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="120dp"
          android:background="@drawable/barcode"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Tap to Scan"
          android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:textSize="18sp"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <!--here is the layout i want to put at the bottom of the page-->
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:id="@+id/bottomView"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:gravity="bottom">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps.